# How to get img src with xpath and php

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I'm getting an empty variable when I use the following xpath formula:

```
foreach ($xpath4->evaluate('/rss/channel/item') as $rssItem) {

    $item_image = $xpath4->evaluate('string(content:encoded/img/@src)', $rssItem);

}
```

Here's the xml portion
:

```
<content:encoded>
            <![CDATA[<div id="attachment_195278" style="width: 4082px" class="wp-caption aligncenter"><img class="size-full wp-image-195278" src="http://website.com/files/2017/03/AP17067056441431.jpg"...
```

How do I get the img src?  I tried experimenting with different syntax/formulas, but they all return an empty variable.  I also can't find any examples of xpath in a for each loop targeting an img src within a content encoded tag.

Edit: I attempted to parse the CDATA with PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser, however, I kept getting the error, "PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function find() on a non-object."  So I treated the CDATA as a string and parsed it with a function I found:

```
function getBetween($content,$start,$end){
  $r = explode($start, $content);
  if (isset($r[1])){
    $r = explode($end, $r[1]);
    return $r[0];
}
  return '';
}

foreach ($xpath4->evaluate('/rss/channel/item') as $rssItem) {

  $item_image = $xpath4->evaluate('string(content:encoded)', $rssItem);

  $content = $item_image;
  $start = 'src="';
  $end = '" alt=';
  $item_image = getBetween($content,$start,$end);

  echo $item_image;

}
```

Comment: `CDATA` in XML is not parsed, as if it's just a single string/text node... the parse won't know there is `img` tag with `src` attribute etc..

Comment: So, do you know what I need to do to get the src?

Comment: Get the content of the CDATA and try to parse it separately (maybe using HTML parser if it doesn't conform to XML format)

Comment: I'll give it a try and check back.  Thanks.